# Are linked contact links ever sent to Google?

Tags: contacts, google-account, privacy

Assume I have a friend who is using an [anonymous Threema ID](https://threema.ch/en/faq/threema_id). That ID has no phone number and no email address associated with it.

That person also has an email address and a phone number, both of which are saved in my address book on my Android phone and in my Gmail contacts.

If I now link those two contacts, will that link ever be sent to Google or will the link only exist locally on my phone?

Comment: [FAQ](https://threema.ch/en/faq) implies that If you have enabled *Account* permission, it will otherwise won't. **Accounts:** *Used for contact synchronization resp. integration into the account management of Android*

Comment: That only touches on syncing Threema with Android Contacts. This question is about whether Android Contact links are sent to Google Servers.

Comment: Both are connected aren't they? What would be the point of syncing with Android, except to sync with Android account ( in turn Google servers?) I don't use this app so can't verify for sure

Comment: They may be, but don't need to be.